# What can user do with VIEW SERVER STATE permissions?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, permissions, database, database-administration

In SQL Server 2008 there is a permissions VIEW SERVER STATE. What rights this permission give to user? What SQL Server mean by SERVER STATE?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Read [Dynamic Management Views and Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188754.aspx)

Dynamic management views and functions return server state information that can be used to monitor the health of a server instance, diagnose problems, and tune performance.

There are two types of dynamic management views and functions:

- **Server-scoped** dynamic management views and functions. These require `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission on the server.
- **Database-scoped** dynamic management views and functions. These require `VIEW DATABASE STATE` permission on the database.

Comment: I would mention that there are security implications for allowing the use of DMV's and DMF's -- in particular, they allow looking at queries and query parameters, which can contain confidential info.  Not a problem if there is only one database on the server and the user can already look at everything in the DB.  But how often is that the case?

Comment: VIEW SERVER STATE is a sufficient privilege which, applied to the login account, also induces VIEW DATABASE STATE in all databases in which the login account is associated with an SQL user. However, it would also be necessary to have the SHOWPLAN privilege to be able to read the query execution plans...